# XSLT - Not applying the template

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to print on html some XML code with XSLT, but it is not working properly.I'm still newbie and I'm not watching the problem.

This is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="order" />
            <xsl:if test="@type='OUTPUT'">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="{class}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="i">
    <i>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </i>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b">
    <b>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </b>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="u">
    <u>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </u>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="del">
    <del>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </del>
</xsl:template>
```

And this is my XML example code:

```
<elements>
    <element type='OUTPUT'>
        <value>
            <b>
                <u>Personal information</u>
            </b>
        </value>
        <class>col-md-12 output</class>
        <order>2</order>
    </element>
</elements>
```

All works fine except the `<b>` and `<u>` tags.

This is what I'm obtaining:

[image]

My expected Output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 output">
            <b>
                <u>Personal information</u>
            </b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Someone knows where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the expected output? At first glance your problem comes from the fact that you only iterate `elements/element` so you `<b>` and `<u>` templates never get a chance to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `xsl:apply-templates` if you want your templates to be applied e.g. instead of

```
                        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
```

use

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly! Could you explain me why I need to use `xsl:apply-templates`? I don't have any `xsl:template` who matches with the value tag. I'm trying to learn and understand this king of issues.

Comment: As you want to have your templates for the descendants of the `value` element to have effect, you need to make sure the element itself is processed in a way that uses templates, `<xsl:value-of select="value"/>` does not do that, while `<xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>` does, due to the use of the built-in templates https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `xsl:apply-templates` in your first template.
Change it to

```
<div class="{class}">
    <xsl:apply-templates  />
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</div>
```